# Why is this parameter invalid in sklearn's Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error for the below code, but cannot figure out why my parameter is invalid. `SelectFromModel` is a valid input in a Pipeline as it has a fit and transform function.

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter sfm_threshold for estimator Pipeline.
Check the list of available parameters with
`estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV, LinearRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

poly = PolynomialFeatures()
std = StandardScaler()
ls = LassoCV(cv=10)
sfm = SelectFromModel(estimator=ls)
lr = LinearRegression()

pipe_lr = Pipeline([('poly', poly),
                    ('std', std),
                    ('sfm', sfm),
                    ('lr', lr)])

param_range_degree = [2, 3]
param_range_threshold = [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5]

param_grid_lr = [{'poly__degree': param_range_degree,
                  'sfm__threshold': param_range_threshold}]
```

When I run `pipe_lr.get_params().keys()` I get the following output, which does in fact include `sfm__threshold`, which I copy and pasted exactly as is.

```
 ['std__with_mean',
 'sfm__estimator__precompute',
 'lr__n_jobs',
 'sfm__prefit',
 'poly',
 'sfm__threshold',
 'sfm__estimator__cv',
 'sfm__estimator__max_iter',
 'sfm__estimator__positive',
 'sfm__estimator__n_alphas',
 'std__with_std',
 'sfm__estimator__random_state',
 'std__copy',
 'lr__normalize',
 'sfm__estimator__copy_X',
 'lr',
 'sfm__estimator__n_jobs',
 'poly__interaction_only',
 'sfm__estimator__fit_intercept',
 'sfm__estimator__tol',
 'sfm__estimator',
 'sfm__estimator__verbose',
 'sfm',
 'sfm__estimator__normalize',
 'std',
 'sfm__estimator__selection',
 'poly__degree',
 'lr__copy_X',
 'sfm__estimator__alphas',
 'lr__fit_intercept',
 'steps',
 'poly__include_bias',
 'sfm__estimator__eps']
```

Comment: Could you please give us a *[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)* of your problem?

Comment: By putting the parentheses onto the function the type of the instance passed across the assignment is the return type of the function not type function.  My guess is that the pipe line is looking to take a function as a parameter where you pass a non-function.

Comment: I have no error while executing your code. Are you using python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: No error here too! It works fine! I used python 3 and sklearn 0.17.1.

Answer (score 6):

This is simple typographical error, you pass `sfm_threshold` and you should `sfm__threshold` (notice **double** underscore). At least this is what the error at the very beginning shows.